# nothing returned by comparing BigDecimal list to long list

Tags: java, java-7

I have a list of `BigDecimal`, and a list of the entity which have a long field, I want to add any entity that it's long attribute contained in the `BigDecimal` list.
I don't know what's happening, I get an empty list.

```
public List<Utilisateur> signataireUsersOfDoc (List<BigDecimal> list) {
    List <Utilisateur> filledList = utilisateurDAO.findAll();
    List <Utilisateur> filteredList = new ArrayList<Utilisateur>() ;
    BigDecimal n;
        
    for (Utilisateur temp : filledList) {
        n = new BigDecimal(temp.getPoste().getIdPoste());
        if (list.contains(n)) {
            filteredList.add(temp) ;
        }
     }
     return filteredList; 
}
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you using a `BigDecimal` for what you're calling an ID?

Comment: This does not look like a minimal example. Please make it smaller. Drop `filledList` and `filteredList`.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel uh? They seem pretty important. If anything we would need *more* information, as in what's in `list` and what's in `filledList`.

Comment: Fine, either drop the lists or tell us what an `Utilisateur` is. The question, as I can decipher it, talks about the `BigDecimals` only.

Comment: And, @FedericoklezCulloca, the answers also only talk about `BigDecimal`. My assumptions was right, and your “uh?” was displaced.

Answer (score 2):

When calling `List#contains`, the `equals` method is called on each object, trying to find a match (until one is found).

The problem is, the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method of the `BigDecimal` class is problematic, namely:

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality.
> Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal
> only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to
> 2.00 when compared by this method).

which can cause a lot of headache.

Since you're using Java7 and don't have access to streams, create a helper method (to keep your code clean), which will compare the value by the `BigDecimal#compareTo` method and use that one in place of direct `List#contains` call:

```
private static boolean listContains(List<BigDecimal> list, BigDecimal value) {
    for (BigDecimal item : list) {
        if (item.compareTo(value) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

public List<Utilisateur> signataireUsersOfDoc (List<BigDecimal> list) {
    List <Utilisateur> filledList = utilisateurDAO.findAll();
    List <Utilisateur> filteredList = new ArrayList<Utilisateur>() ;
    BigDecimal n;
        
    for (Utilisateur temp : filledList) {
        n = new BigDecimal(temp.getPoste().getIdPoste());
        if (listContains(list, n)) {
            filteredList.add(temp) ;
        }
     }
     return filteredList; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of `BigDecimal.equals` is:

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality. Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

Hence 100 and 100.00 are different.

*The answer of Andy already pointed this out.*

And as a `List.contains` is slow anyways, use a `Set<Long>`:

```
public List<Utilisateur> signataireUsersOfDoc (List<BigDecimal> list) {
    Set<Long> set = list.stream().map(bd -> bd.longValue()).collect(Collect.toSet());

    List <Utilisateur> filledList = utilisateurDAO.findAll();
    List <Utilisateur> filteredList = new ArrayList<Utilisateur>() ;
    for (Utilisateur temp : filledList) {
        long n = temp.getPoste().getIdPoste();
        if (set.contains(n)) {
            filteredList.add(temp) ;
        }
     }
     return filteredList; 
}
```

The real solution would however be something like:

```
    Set<Long> set = list.stream().map(bd -> bd.longValue()).collect(Collect.toSet());

    return utilisateurDAO.findWhere(CriteriaBuilder.idPoste.in(set));
```

*(Pseudo-code)*