# containsAll returning different responses in case of Map and HashSet

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap, hashset

Objective : Trying to replicate the behaviour of `compareEmployeesMap` in `compareEmployees` in a simpler way. However, I'm getting different response with what I tried. I have overridden the hashcode and equals method in both, the Manager and Owner class. Not sure what I am doing wrong hence I'm asking here. Thank you for your guidance.

note : If i use the constructor with just the `encodedkey`, it works as expected. The constructor with `DecimalFields` seems to be a problem.

I have added the snippet below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Human> oldEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    oldEmployees.add(new Owner("1", new DecimalFields(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.ONE), 10));
    oldEmployees.add(new Manager("2", new DecimalFields(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.ONE)));

    List<Human> newEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    newEmployees.add(new Owner("1", new DecimalFields(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.ONE), 10));
    newEmployees.add(new Manager("2", new DecimalFields(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.ONE)));
    //newEmployees.add(new Manager("3", new DecimalFields(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.ONE)));


    System.out.println(compareEmployees(oldEmployees, newEmployees));
    System.out.println(compareEmployeesMap(oldEmployees, newEmployees));
}

private static boolean compareEmployees(List<Human> oldEmployees, List<Human> newEmployees) {
    return !new HashSet<>(newEmployees).containsAll(oldEmployees);
}

private static boolean compareEmployeesMap(List<Human> oldEmployees, List<Human> newEmployees) {
    Map<String, Boolean> oldEmployeesMap = oldEmployees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.
                    toMap(Human::getEncodedKey,
                            Manager.class::isInstance));

    if(!oldEmployeesMap.entrySet().isEmpty()){
        Map<String, Boolean> newEmployeesMap = newEmployees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(Human::getEncodedKey,
                                Manager.class::isInstance));

        return !newEmployeesMap.entrySet().containsAll(oldEmployeesMap.entrySet());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Owner Class :

```
public class Owner implements Human {

private String encodedKey;

private DecimalFields decimalFields;

private Integer age;

public Owner(String encodedKey) {
    this.encodedKey = encodedKey;
}

public Owner(String encodedKey, DecimalFields decimalFields, Integer age) {
    this.encodedKey = encodedKey;
    this.decimalFields = decimalFields;
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String getEncodedKey() {
    return encodedKey;
}

public DecimalFields getDecimalFields() {
    return decimalFields;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Owner)) return false;
    Owner owner = (Owner) o;
    return Objects.equals(encodedKey, owner.getEncodedKey())
            && Objects.equals(decimalFields, owner.getDecimalFields())
            && Objects.equals(age, owner.getAge());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(encodedKey, decimalFields, age);
}
}
```

Manager Class :

```
public class Manager implements Human {

private String encodedKey;

private DecimalFields decimalFields;

public Manager(String encodedKey, DecimalFields decimalFields) {
    this.encodedKey = encodedKey;
    this.decimalFields = decimalFields;
}

public Manager(String encodedKey) {
    this.encodedKey = encodedKey;
}

@Override
public String getEncodedKey() {
    return encodedKey;
}

public DecimalFields getDecimalFields() {
    return decimalFields;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Manager)) return false;
    Manager manager = (Manager) o;
    return Objects.equals(encodedKey, manager.getEncodedKey())
            && Objects.equals(decimalFields, manager.getDecimalFields());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(encodedKey, decimalFields);
}
}
```

DecimalFields class :

```
public class DecimalFields {

private BigDecimal min;
private BigDecimal max;
private BigDecimal defaultValue;

public DecimalFields(BigDecimal min, BigDecimal max, BigDecimal defaultValue) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
}

public Optional<BigDecimal> getMin() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(min);
}

public Optional<BigDecimal> getMax() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(max);
}

public Optional<BigDecimal> getDefaultValue() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(defaultValue);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof DecimalFields)) return false;
    DecimalFields that = (DecimalFields) o;
    return Objects.equals(min, that.getMin())
            && Objects.equals(max, that.getMax())
            && Objects.equals(defaultValue, that.getDefaultValue());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(min, max, defaultValue);
}
}
```

interface Human :

```
public interface Human {

public String getEncodedKey();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Owner and Manager classes as well, or atleast the getEncodedKey function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i discovered this :

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality.
> Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal
> only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to
> 2.00 when compared by this method).

Influenced by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63599586/3755885) answer, I was able to resolve this issue :

```
private static boolean compareEmployees(List<Human> oldEmployees, List<Human> newEmployees) {
    Set<String> setOldEmp = oldEmployees.stream().map(bd -> bd.getEncodedKey()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<String> setNewEmp = newEmployees.stream().map(bd -> bd.getEncodedKey()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    return !setNewEmp.containsAll(setOldEmp);
}
```